# How to buy something on ebay using node.js?

Tags: node.js, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I would like to write a node.js script that would buy items on ebay using ebay buy API.

The problem is that ebay documentation is terrible and i can't find an explanation on how to checkout an item?

I tried finding node.js libraries with such feature implemented - which in 2020 i would hope exist - but turns out none of the libraries have buy implemented.

Has anybody figure out how to it?

I'm sorry i wish i have some code snippets to post here but i fail to find even the most basic code snippets to be used as starting point :(

Comment: You can create your own API, and it's quite simple. Open up your browser and DevTools to monitor HTTP requests sent to Ebay. Then, you can use the node [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to emulate those requests.